# How get the Vue instance from vuetify with vue-axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I create a project with Vuetify and vue-axios, and create a simple login component, but I have problem to get the Vue instance

this is my login component:

```
  <template>
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-content>
          <v-container fluid fill-height>
            <v-layout align-center justify-center>
              <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
                <v-card class="elevation-12">
                  <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                   ...
                  </v-toolbar>
                  <v-card-text>
                    ...
                  </v-card-text>
                  <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn color="primary" @click='logar()'>Entrar</v-btn>
                  </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-content>
      </v-app>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'Login',
      data: () => ({
        drawer: null,
        checkbox: false,
        username: 'cartorio@teste.com.br',
        password: '1234',
      }),
      props: {
        source: String,
      },
      methods: {    
        logar() {   
          var myVue = this.$vuetify;
          this.axios.post('http://localhost:8585/login', {
            email: this.username,
            senha: this.password,
          },
          {
            withCredentials: false,
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
          ).then((response) => {
//HERE I NEED TO USE myVue
            window.AUT = response.headers.authorization;
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

so, inside axios promisse, then I need to use my var myVue, so why always get undefined?

tks

Comment: From your current code, you can simply use it. The arrow function keeps the context. Are you getting `undefined` as it is?

Comment: See how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/w4bbgnaz/2/ (hit `ENTRAR` and watch the console).

Comment: work here too.. can be beucase I dont restart the server? I using npm run dev

Comment: I don't know. What is not working, exactly?